# How to get the source code of Job

Tags: sas, sas-dis

Sorry for the English language skills!

`SAS version 9.3`

It is necessary to automate the process of obtaining the source code of `Job`. I know the way through deploy/redeploy, but it is not suitable for the creation of deploy metadata.

Through macro:

```
data job_source_code;
  length uri source_uri $256.;
  length text $1000.;
  _rc = metadata_getnobj("omsobj:Job?@Name='JOB_NAME'", 1, uri);
  _rc = METADATA_GETNASN(uri, 'SourceCode', 1, source_uri);
  _rc = METADATA_GETATTR(source_uri, 'StoredText', text);
run;
```

But the field `text` is always empty.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way to automate the process of obtaining the source code of `Job`?

Comment: The source code of Data Integration Studio jobs is not stored in metadata. You need DIS to generate it and deploy it. Then you can read it from the external file.

Comment: A good resource:

http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/210-2007.pdf

Comment: I can generate source code is not in the DIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's too late that I am answering the question. Recently I have got the same request, before trying did a search in the Web to see if I can get any code. But was not able to find any, luckily I found your code and worked on completing the remaining part. Thanks.

```
data server_details_in_smc_1;
    length uri $256 Name PublicType TransId_uri  $100  text f_Direct SourceCode_Location $1000.;
    nobj=1;
    n=1;

    do while(nobj >= 0);
        n=n+1;
        nobj=metadata_getnobj("omsobj:Job?@Id contains '.'",n,uri);

        if (nobj > 0) then
            do;
                arc=metadata_getattr(uri,"Name",Name);
                arc=metadata_getattr(uri,"PublicType",PublicType);
                TransId_obj=metadata_getnasn(uri,'SourceCode',1,TransId_uri);
                arc = metadata_getnasn(TransId_uri,"Directories",1,f_Direct);
                arc = metadata_getattr(f_Direct,"DirectoryName",SourceCode_Location);
                output ;
                end;
    end;
    keep Name PublicType SourceCode_Location ;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use batch file to deploy jobs from commend line.

I've never done this. But you can find description of this procedure in DI Stuio User's Guide:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etlug/65807/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1jxhqhaz10gj2n1pyr0hbzozv2f.htm

Comment: Thank you. I know about it. It does not suit me.